# Hashing Rails result into Array objects JSON

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I have a rails query like this

```
@c = RealEstateAgentAssignmentStatus.joins(:real_estate_agent_assignments =>:loan_application)
    .group("real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.assignment_status").select("real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.assignment_status,count(real_estate_assignments.loan_application_id)")
    .where("real_estate_agent_assignments.real_estate_agent_id = 188").count
```

ok i have a rails result in json format like this

var data =   {
       "Rejected By Customer/Bank":1,
       "Failed Screening":2,
       "Submitted":2,
       "Processing Stage":3
    }

It is in json because i have to pass it to angularJS and use it there.

Right now i can only call it like this

```
data["Submitted]
```

How can i hash my result in rails or put the results into an array whereby i can call it like this

```
data.status , data.value
```

I thought about mapping it in rails but it was giving me an error.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### In Ruby:

```
ary = data.map do |k,v|
    {
        status: k,
        value: v
    }
end
```

### In Javascript:

```
var ary = [];
angular.forEach(data, function(k,v){ 
  this.push({ status: k, value: v }) 
}, ary);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rails**

USE [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)

```
require 'ostruct'
data = {"status" => 'Rejected By Customer/Bank', "value" => 1}
os = OpenStruct.new data
os.status # Rejected By Customer/Bank
os.value # 1
```

Or you can define you own method_missing in Hash class. But it's not a very good idea.

```
def method_missing(m)
  key = m.to_s
  return self[key] if self.has_key? key
  super
end
```

In all my cases you need Hash with keys `status` and `value`. To convert your hash:

```
new_hash = h.map{ |key, value| OpenStruct.new({status: key, value: value }) }
```

or without OpenStruct:

```
new_hash = h.map{ |key, value| {status: key, value: value } }
```

After this you can use:

```
new_hash[i].status
new_hash[i].value
```

**JavaScript**

In js convert you hash to array of objects. With angular.js:

```
var data = [];
angular.forEach(your_json, function(k,v){ 
  this.push({ status: k, value: v }) 
}, data);
```

Hope that understand you correct and it's help